# Trying to find out Azure latency between on premises client and azure cloud application

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, server-side

I am trying to accomplish one task which is below.
What I am doing it.

1. All my users are on Premises.
2. Application is hosted on Azure VM IaaS.

Question =>
Azure cloud application talk with Internet and download huge packages and share with client which is on- Primes. So I am trying to understand the Risk and latency matrix between on-Prime users and Azure cloud application.
If any one has done some sort of thing and encounter latency issues and what will be possible fixes for that?

Note=> I can't Migrate user to Azure cloud as of now.

Answer (score 0):

**To encounter latency issues, please try the following:**

- To reduce the latency between on premises client and azure cloud application make use of [**Azure HPC cache**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/hpc-cache/).

> **Azure HPC Cache reduces latency for applications where data may be tethered to existing infrastructure because of dataset sizes and operational scale.**

- **Azure HPC caches** active data automatically that is present in both on-premises and in Azure.
- You can make use of **Accelerated networking** where communication will be done more fast.
- Try eliminating **network congestion**.
- Try reducing number of **network nodes** needed to traverse from one stage to another.
- Make use of **Azure ExpressRoute** and **Azure Analysis Services** to reduce Network latency.
- **Azure ExpressRoute** creates a private connection between on-premises sources and the Azure.
- **Azure Analysis Services** avoids the need for an on-premises data gateway and generally eliminates network latency.

For more in detail, please **refer** below links:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-hpc-cache-reducing-latency-between-azure-and-on-premises-storage/

https://blogit.create.pt/gustavobrito/2017/11/27/latency-test-between-azure-and-on-premises-intro/

https://viniciusdeschamps.com.br/3-ways-to-reduce-network-latency-in-azure/#how-can-I-measure-network-latency